# not able to get component variables under setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am new to Angular(6) and I am getting this problem that I am not able to get component variables under setTimeout function. Take a look on code, explaining my issue there.

```
    export class ConSellerDraftsolSecOneComponent implements OnInit {
      draftSolutionForm: FormGroup;

    //Other code

    //ngOnIt
     ngOnInit() {
        this.draftSolutionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          title: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
          product: [''],
        })
    }

    //function
     autosavedraftsolution() {
    //here, it is working
     console.log(this.draftSolutionForm);
     setTimeout(function () {
     //here, it is not working, showing "undefined" and even intellisense is not supporting me here to do this
     console.log(this.draftSolutionForm);
        }, 3000);
      }
   }
```

Help me to identify the reason. Thank you.

Comment: try with lambda and setInterval( () => { console.log(this.draftSolutionForm}, 3000);

Comment: Might be due to arrow function -> `var ref= this;` and `ref.draftSolutionForm` will solve your problem

Comment: Like @bookboy noted - `function() {}` creates it's own scope, thus using `this` inside it's body will refer to the context of the function. To retain the original scope you should use lambda/arrow function `() => {}`

Comment: @ful-stackz an arrow function also creates its own scope. Every function does. `this` doesn't refer to the *scope* but rather to the *context*. These are different. Arrow functions bind to the lexical scope at creation time, you can achieve a similar result doing `(function() {}).bind(this)` but arrow functions are more concise way of expressing it. For comparison `function a() {  function b() {}  }` means that `b` is within the scope of `a` and you cannot change that at runtime.\

Comment: @vlaz Thank you for the clarification! I misused the terms and probably confused the author, so thank you for your input!

Comment: @vlaz Thanks for your wonderful explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a lambda expression:

```
setTimeout(() => {
 console.log(this.draftSolutionForm);
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: () => this called arrow function may people get confused you said lambda ,you just remind me to c# days ,up for lambda expression

Answer (score 1):

This is because within a function(), *this* points to the context of the function.

```
autosavedraftsolution() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    //here, it is not working and even intellisense is not supporting me here
    console.log(this.draftSolutionForm);
  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I really appreciate it.

Comment: in short arrow function bind to the current this , and it common to use in the class body like this

Answer (score 1):

```
 export class ConSellerDraftsolSecOneComponent implements OnInit {
      draftSolutionForm: FormGroup;

    //Other code

    //ngOnIt
     ngOnInit() {
        this.draftSolutionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          title: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
          product: [''],
        })
    }

    //function
     autosavedraftsolution() {
    //here, it is working
     console.log(this.draftSolutionForm);
     setTimeout(() => {console.log(this.draftSolutionForm);}, 3000);


      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

> .bind(this)

```
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(this.draftSolutionForm);
}.bind(this), 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

ES6/2015 An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own `this`

```
setTimeout(() => {
 // this => ConSellerDraftsolSecOneComponent 
 console.log(this.draftSolutionForm);
 }, 3000);
```

Or you can defined a variable to access to `this` (lexical scope)

```
let _this = this;
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(_this.draftSolutionForm);
}, 3000);
```

Finaly `bind` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called

```
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(this.draftSolutionForm);
}.bind(this), 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I really appreciate it.